Text formula to pull text between special character "|"
I am trying to build a formula similar to the one mentioned above. The source of the field is a text value such as the following examples.
Transfer | Edna (Edna) Garcia | Motherboard LLC |
The goal is to pull the text in bold, i.e. Motherboard LLC.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should also [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far. If you're encountering any error messages, you need to share them with us as well (in full, do not try to shorten them because you will leave out important information).

If you're new to formulas, you should do Trailhead tutorials and also do web searches on using formulas to extract portions of text from a field.  There are many good resources out there.

is it always the 3rd column?  Can the pipe | be escaped within a column?

I am going to assume that there will always be just 3 columns.
This can be solved by doing the following:

Find the position of the first |
Remove the part of the text up until after the first |
Repeat the process until you are left with the final column.
Lastly, remove the last two characters at the end of the string.

As this is quite a long formula, it is always good to test it in steps.
I created a custom field TestString__c which will have the original string in it.
I then created the formula field and started building the formula:

FIND("|", TestString__c)) is equal to 10, which is the position of the first |.
I then use the formula RIGHT to remove the text up until the first |:

RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)) 

which is equal to Edna (Edna) Garcia | Motherboard LLC |

I then created a second formula to retrieve the position of the second | in Edna (Edna) Garcia | Motherboard LLC |:

FIND("|",RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)))

which is equal to 21

Now I update the RIGHT formula that I created in step 2:

RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)-FIND("|",RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c))))

which is equal to Motherboard LLC |

The last thing is to remove the 2 characters at the end. This can be done with a LEFT formula:

LEFT(RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)-FIND("|",RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c))),LEN(RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)-FIND("|",RIGHT(TestString__c, LEN(TestString__c)-FIND("|", TestString__c)))))-2)

which will give you Motherboard LLC

Good luck!

Thank you, Adriaan! That worked for me.

Glad to hear it @ShehryarRana If you don't mind, can you mark my answer as the one that did the trick? I would really appreciate it

Hi Adriaan, I just now did it. Thank you once again!

Thanks @ShehryarRana
